# Show that the maximum of $|f|$ in $\{w\in\mathbb{C}: |w-z|\le r\}$ is in the border

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble proving the following:

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic funcion in $\mathbb{C}$.
Show that if $|f|$ has an absolute maximum in $\{w\in\mathbb{C}: |w-z|\le r\}$, then that maximum is in the border of that set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is what you are allowed to use in the proof. A proof I am aware of uses the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)). Assume the maximum of $\vert f \vert$ is not in the border (and different from zero). Then there is an open neighbourhood $U$ on which $\vert f (z) \vert $ is different from zero. By the open mapping theorem we have that $f(U)$ is open and therefore $\vert f(U) \vert$ is also open. So $\vert f \vert$ didn't attain a maximum in $U$ in the first place.